# Porque os dados estão sumindo ao dar refresh nessa página?

Tags: php, session, post, checkbox

Enquanto eu uso [***esse filtro***](http://new.pier36imoveis.com.br) para buscar imóveis, tudo vai bem ***mas*** na hora que eu dou refresh na página, o checkbox faz a busca sumir. Ele desfaz todo o `session` ou pelo menos dá um erro no filtro que não permite de continuar a recuperar as outras `sessions`.

Como eu posso melhorar este script para que a busca não seja desfeita ao dar um refresh na página? Repito, o checkbox está fazendo isso.

```
$civil = [];

if(isset($_POST['busca-implacavel'])) {

    if( isset( $_POST['tipo'] ) ) $_SESSION['tipo'] = $_POST['tipo'];
    if( isset( $_POST['civil'] ) ) $_SESSION['civil'] = $_POST['civil'];
    if( isset( $_POST['cidade'] ) ) $_SESSION['cidade'] = $_POST['cidade'];
    if( isset( $_POST['valorminimo'] ) ) $_SESSION['valorminimo'] = $_POST['valorminimo'];
    if( isset( $_POST['valormaximo'] ) ) $_SESSION['valormaximo'] = $_POST['valormaximo'];

    $tipo = isset( $_SESSION['tipo'] ) ? $_SESSION['tipo'] : '';
    $civil = isset( $_SESSION['civil'] ) ? $_SESSION['civil'] : '';
    $cidade = isset( $_SESSION['cidade'] ) ? $_SESSION['cidade'] : '';
    $valorminimo = isset( $_SESSION['valorminimo'] ) ? $_SESSION['valorminimo'] : '';
    $valormaximo = isset( $_SESSION['valormaximo'] ) ? $_SESSION['valormaximo'] : '';

}
```

Eis o código dos campos do formulário relacionado ao `checkbox`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="civil[]" value="solteiro" <?php echo in_array("solteiro", $civil) ? " checked='checked'" : ""; ?>>Solteiro<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="civil[]" value="casado"  <?php echo in_array("casado", $civil) ? " checked='checked'" : ""; ?>>Casado<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="civil[]" value="viuvo"  <?php echo in_array("viuvo", $civil) ? " checked='checked'" : ""; ?>>Viúvo<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="civil[]" value="divorciado"  <?php echo in_array("divorciado", $civil) ? " checked='checked'" : ""; ?>>Divorciado<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="civil[]" value="uniaoestavel"  <?php echo in_array("uniaoestavel", $civil) ? " checked='checked'" : ""; ?>>União Estável<br>
```

> Dá pra reparar logo abaixo no `print_r($_SESSION)` que o sistema
>   continua retornando os `índices` do `array $civil` mas não aplica o
>   `checked`.

Obrigado :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erro de lógica. Você só está recuperando a SESSION se houver POST no seu código.

O correto é apenas a parte dos $_POST dentro do `if`, o resto fora:

```
if(isset($_POST['busca-implacavel'])) {
    if( isset( $_POST['tipo'] ) ) $_SESSION['tipo'] = $_POST['tipo'];
    if( isset( $_POST['civil'] ) ) $_SESSION['civil'] = $_POST['civil'];
    if( isset( $_POST['cidade'] ) ) $_SESSION['cidade'] = $_POST['cidade'];
    if( isset( $_POST['valorminimo'] ) ) $_SESSION['valorminimo'] = $_POST['valorminimo'];
    if( isset( $_POST['valormaximo'] ) ) $_SESSION['valormaximo'] = $_POST['valormaximo'];
}

// Daqui pra baixo não depende se tem o POST ou não, então é fora do if.

$tipo = isset( $_SESSION['tipo'] ) ? $_SESSION['tipo'] : '';
$civil = isset( $_SESSION['civil'] ) ? $_SESSION['civil'] : array();
$cidade = isset( $_SESSION['cidade'] ) ? $_SESSION['cidade'] : '';
$valorminimo = isset( $_SESSION['valorminimo'] ) ? $_SESSION['valorminimo'] : '';
$valormaximo = isset( $_SESSION['valormaximo'] ) ? $_SESSION['valormaximo'] : '';
```

Certifique-se de ter o `session_start()` no topo da página, antes disso tudo.

Um detalhe: o *array* você precisa inicializar assim:

```
$civil = isset( $_SESSION['civil'] ) ? $_SESSION['civil'] : array();
```

Comment: Desatenção !!! Estava desatento, é a fome :)

Comment: Bem interessante a solução ... estou aprendendo muito ... Obrigado Bacco ...